# How to create proxy class to pass the object to web service in Android

Tags: android, web-services

How to create proxy class to pass the object to web service in Android?

I.E.: I have to post more than 10000 characters to web service, it shows 404 exception. So i need to create proxy class and pass a proxy class object to the server. 
So how do I create the proxy class?

Comment: In J2ME I codded before and I see that on android there is no proxy class generator. Even java supports proxy generation some part of axis excluded and some of your real axis jars you referenced cause conflicts with android classes. So I'm wondering as much as you how can it be?

Comment: here is a good point for odata access but still looking for classic access http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/09/13/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet.aspx